# Android build strips ogg metadata

Tags: android, apk, metadata, ogg

I have some .ogg files that I want to copy to the notifications folder and use them in my App for notifications (and have available for other apps). They all have a Title in the metadata and I'm putting them in the /res/raw folder but when I build the apk I the Title metadata is gone. (I extracted them from the apk and did a diff).

Is there a way to stop stripping the data? I can't seem to find any clues in my searches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell aapt is stripping the metadata to keep the APK size down. I was not able to find any way to stop this from happening. The title without metadata will come from the file name which has the resource filename restrictions (lowercase separated with _). I did notice that the Facebook app also copies the pop notification to the notification folder and it's missing the title as well. I'm pretty sure it used to have a more user friendly title (it's currently facebook_ringtone_app). So the metadata stripping may be a new issue.

I was able to move my files to the assets folder and copy them from there without losing the metadata. So if you have files with metadata, at the moment the assets folder is probably the way to go.